# Wake from hibernate on ssh request

Tags: 10.04, networking, ssh, suspend, hibernate

Is there a feature (or aptitude package) in Ubuntu 10.04 that will wake my computer up from standby when it gets an ssh (or other webrequest).

I've been trying to put my computer in hibernate/standby when I'm not running code in an effort to "go green" at my university.  However, I often need to ssh into my computer over the weekend to do work.  However, it does not seem to "wake-up" to hear this request.  I remember on my old windows machine there was a "Wake-on-LAN" option to the hibernate command.  So if I needed to remote-desktop in while it was asleep it would wake up.

Can anyone request a good way to replicate this feature?

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 7):

You need *some* device on your local network which can send the WOL package needed. It must be the local network because the package isn't forwarded by routers to other network segments.

The perfect device to do this, would be your router.  Unfortunately very few routers support this, but if you get one which use OpenWRT or similar you can install software which can generate the necessary WOL packet waking up the machine you actually want to talk to.

Comment: Yes, this is a really important point and mostly missed by the other commentators.  If you are at home, and you want to wake up a machine at your university, you can't do that unless there's some other machine at your university you can go into first.  Therefore probably the best option is to put the machine into a low-power-but-not-suspended state (eg cpu sleep, disk sleep, etc), from which a regular network packet can wake it.  In the future maybe we can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_Proxy_Service

Comment: Since I wrote the answer, I've purchased a Time Capsule (Apple router with harddisk) which contains such a proxy which allows Mac's to go to sleep and still be visible to other Mac's.  Very impressive.  I have not investigated if this can be used with Linux machines.

Comment: You may also want to consider a cheap powerefficient computer to do this.  A raspberry pi comes to mind.

Answer (score 5):

The Ubuntu Forums has an excellent [Guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=234588). You will need to wake the machine with a WOL packet before you ssh in though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe here it the [link](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO_set_up_Wake-On-Lan_%28Ubuntu%29) that would help you out :)

There are clear instructions for setting up to WOL (wake on lan)

Comment: I'll check it out Monday ... my computer is currently hibernating for the weekend ;)

Comment: @judowill haha no problem. let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: I don't know if you are connected to the author of the linked answer, but if you are please not that the copy-paste-into-commandline doesn't work well due to the appearance of bangs in the answer, which under bash get changed....

Answer (score 0):

Wake On LAN is something you can enable in the BIOS.

Comment: yeah but the system has to be aware of it as well. yeah but making it the bios setting is on is the first step outlined in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an OpenWRT/Tomato based router, [a shell script I wrote](http://blog.oxplot.com/wake-up-on-ssh/) that runs on the router and wakes up any PC that's receiving an incoming SSH connection, might be of use to you.

Comment: Page not found...